# When switching the horizontal screen, the interface is fitted with vertical screen.How should I fix it

Tags: react-native

When switching the horizontal screen, the interface is fitted with vertical screen

**This is my code**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Root from './src/root';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

export class App extends PureComponent {
  componentWillMount(){
    Orientation.lockToLandscape()
  };
  render() {
    return (
        <Root />
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**Initial loading**
[image: Sample Image]

**and then I reload my app is Fine**
[image: Sample Image]

#### *How should I fix it*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a `this.forceUpdate()` to trigger a rerender?

你只有在`componentWillMount()`的時候`lockToLandscape()`但app根本沒有被rerender所以當然顯示不出來啊

Comment: 我是想 加载前转化横屏 , 然后我适配的是横屏的就可以了 . 结果是显示是第一个图那样适配到竖屏的 . 但是重新reload一下就可以了.